# How to debug CMT transaction boundaries?

Tags: sql, transactions, jboss, jta

I have been studying jboss CMT , and would like to learn how the transaction works from top to bottom, best way would be printing debug information to the log file, I enabled org.hibernate.SQL , however, i am only getting SQL statement , there is no "begin" nor commit type of the transaction related statement in log, remains the same when debuging from org.hibernate.* level.

Did a little googling, answer seems tweaking jbosstx-properties.xml, tried that, didn't help either. Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 3):

I followed the advice found in the first section here:
http://i-proving.com/2010/05/28/enabling-debug-in-jboss-core/
which basically tells you to:

> Set
>   "com.arjuna.common.util.logging.DebugLevel"
>   in the "common" section of
>   /server//conf/jbossjta-properties.xml
>   to 0xffffffff

and make sure your jboss-log4j configuration doesn't filter out these messages.

And started getting these kind of messages in the logs:

```
15:13:00,276 DEBUG [logger] BaseTransaction.commit
15:13:00,283 DEBUG [logger] BaseTransaction.getStatus
15:13:00,283 DEBUG [logger] BaseTransaction.begin
```

(and thousands of others, but that's a different story. It looks like Arjuna/JBoss transactions don't use the logging categories idea)

Tested on JBoss 4.2.3.GA, but I guess you have a completely different version of JBoss, if you tried editing `jbosstx-properties.xml` which my JBoss doesn't have.

Comment: I have tried this , didn't seem to get this in my log, I am using Jboss 5.1.0 GA, also set the debug level in jboss-log4j.xml com.arjuna to be debug level

Comment: Do you get any DEBUG messages in the log? I mean from other components than `com.arjuna`?