# Transaction logging in JBoss 6

Tags: logging, transactions, jboss, jboss6.x

In this question:

[How to debug CMT transaction boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991242/how-to-debug-cmt-transaction-boundaries)

some instructions are given for configuring JBoss to log transaction begin, commit etc. events. I'm using JBoss 6, and don't have the file ".../server/conf/jbossjta-properties.xml". Is is possible to achieve the same logging in this newer version?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to set logging in `jboss-logging.xml` file.

You can find there logger category `com.arjuna.ats` with log level `INFO`.  You can just change it to `TRACE` and check if it works for you.

```xml
<logger category="com.arjuna.ats">
    <level name="TRACE" />
</logger>
```

You can find such information in `log/server.log` file:

```
2011-07-04 21:58:25,861 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BaseTransaction.getStatus
2011-07-04 21:58:25,862 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BaseTransaction.begin
2011-07-04 21:58:25,862 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) StateManager::StateManager( 2, 0 )
2011-07-04 21:58:25,862 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BasicAction::BasicAction()
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BasicAction::Begin() for action-id 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BasicAction::actionInitialise() for action-id 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ActionHierarchy::ActionHierarchy(5)
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ActionHierarchy::add(0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4, 1)
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BasicAction::addChildThread () action 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4 adding Thread[http-127.0.0.1-8080-1,5,jboss]
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) BasicAction::addChildThread () action 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4 adding Thread[http-127.0.0.1-8080-1,5,jboss] result = true
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) TransactionReaper::insert ( BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 300 )
2011-07-04 21:58:25,863 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ReaperElement::ReaperElement ( BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:126a:4e121a3c:1d4 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 300 )
2011-07-04 21:58:25,864 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) TransactionImple.getStatus
2011-07-04 21:58:25,864 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) TransactionImple.registerSynchronization
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using this setting, apart from some messages on start-up, I don't get much extra logging at all, and in particular not transaction boundary events.

Comment: @Matt R, please check my update: set log level on `TRACE`. It shows a lot more information about transaction.

Comment: Strange -- when I set the level to TRACE, I don't get any of the messages you listed above, or indeed, any TRACE level arjuna log messages. I do get DEBUG level messages. (I'm running jboss-6.0.0.Final)

Comment: @Matt R, maybe check if you doesn't change some default login level on handler? For example in default configuration you can log on console only messages with `INFO` priority. In my case it seems that it works, but by default logs are wiritten only to the file. I use JBoss 6.0.0Final on Linux.